# How can I sync a pinvoke callback in a method?

Tags: c#, callback, pinvoke

I have a native dll written in C. One function is to search for Gateway and return after timeout.

In C codes,it's a synchronous process

*search -> callback -> return bool.*

So by the time `find_gw` finished, the `gw_found` has already been called thus we already have the results. Is there a proper way to sync this so that I can get `gwaddr gwname` right after `find_gw`? And I numberred the order it run. `gw_found` is called inside `find_gw` synchronously

```
    var gw_found = new FOUND_GW_CALLBACK(callback) //1.new delegate
     bool pinvokereturn=GwPInvokes.find_gw(broadcastaddr, timeout, gw_found);//2.pinvoke                  
    //4.How to get gwaddr/gwname here
```

where

```
public static bool callback(IntPtr ptr,string gwddr,string gwname)
{
    return true; //3.callback
}
```

Comment: ManualResetEventSlim ... `var mres = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);` in callback `mres.Set()` ... after `GwPInvokes.find_gw` `mres.Wait()` the code after `mres.Wait()` would be called after callback calls `mres.Set()`

Comment: or `TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<string, string>>` `var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<string, string>>();` in callback `tsc.SetResult(new Tuple<string,string>(gwddr, gwname);` after GwPInvokes.find_gw `var result = await tsc.Task;` in  result.Item1 would be `gwddr` and in Item2 `gwname`

Comment: @Selvin This should work. But I was just wondering if we can do this without using a waithandle or building a task. Because the `callbcak` would be called before `find_gw` return. And those public fields are not thread-safe.

Comment: *Because the callbcak would be called before find_gw return* and ???

Comment: So by the time you hit the comment, `gwddr` and `gwname` are already assigned by native code, you don't need to wait.

Comment: emulation of both before and after hit ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/zFveDp ... there is not *public fields*

Comment: Uhh...Okay, you are using lambda there. The complier did some magic and that's why you can send the `tcs` to `callback`. And I mean, functionally this works well. But logically ,we don't need to build a task(at least it consumes resource), since it's already a sync process. But your ansewer is nice, and I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: As `gw_found` is called inside `find_gw` synchronously, `find_gw` returns after `gw_found` finishing.

Comment: we don't need to build a task ... mres will be lighter ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/oz0rkm (the task inside GwPInvokes implementation emulates native threading in your native library)

Comment: @Selvin you misunderstood, in native code , it should run like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/zZVgTh

Comment: if callback is not called multiple times then it doesn't matter ... if is called multiple times then sync call doesnt make sens

Comment: if callback is some kind of predicate and is called multiple times then you sould use SetResult or Set only if you would return true

Comment: @Selvin It's C code and I'm not really a C guy. And this saves my day https://dotnetfiddle.net/SCYXar . It looks weird and non-sync(but it is). Imaging how to do this with out that lambda feature....

Comment: *a proper way to sync* the answer is **there is nothing to sync here** because `find_gw` is sync call ... you are missusing this function as callback should be used as predicate ... [so the implementation is more like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L0QTbu) (callback is called multiple times to find out if gwddr, gwname are the one which you are searching for ...